# Android using OpenGL GLSurfaceview for full screen image

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I am working on an app in which bitmap of full screen size of device is drawn in background and on top of that bitmap UI components having transperancy like listview etc. are drawn. Bitmaps shown in background are fetched from server and at time there are 3 bitmaps that keep on changing one by one to change background view of app.

Now if I draw full screen image on `full HD` screen it will take `1080*1920*4` approx. `8 MB` of `heap` space.
  I am thinking of using OpenGL `GLSurfaceView` for showing background images because in openGL bitmap are assigned memory in `GPU` and it is not part of app heap space. I will set bitmap in GLSurfaceView and after that recyle that 
  bitmap so that it will not take app heap memory and it will save 8 MB of heap memory in `full HD` resolutions.

How do app like intragram, facebook etc. shows images in full screen, do they also use GLSurfaceView to save heap memory. Is this approach correct or is there any drawback in this approach?